# Regular expression to stop at specific character, return null if doesn't match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
|AL;GF=0;ID=17;AF=122|CT;GF=0;ID=15;AF=123|BD;GF=0;ID=1;AF=124|
```

I want to match if CT block (have **CT;** between **|**) has ID=1, i tried:

```
/\|CT;.*?ID=1;(?=.*\|)/
```

But doesn't working.

Code:

```js
let string = '|AL;GF=0;ID=17;AF=122|CT;GF=0;ID=15;AF=123|BD;GF=0;ID=1;AF=124|'
console.log(string.match(/\|CT;.*?ID=1;(?=.*\|)/g))

// return ['|CT;GF=0;ID=15;AF=123|BD;GF=0;ID=1;']
// expected null
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
/\|CT;[^|]*ID=1;/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M69bRu/1).

*Details*:

- `\|CT;` - `|CT;` string
- `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than a `|` char
- `ID=1;` - a fixed string.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = [
  '|AL;GF=0;ID=17;AF=122|CT;GF=0;ID=15;AF=123|BD;GF=0;ID=1;AF=124|',
  '|AL;GF=0;ID=17;AF=122|CT;GF=0;ID=1;AF=123|BD;GF=0;ID=1;AF=124|'
]
for (const string of strings) {
    console.log(string.match(/\|CT;[^|]*ID=1;/)?.[0]);
}
```